# Converting base64 encoded bytes to string different in Javascript and C#

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

I have an image & when I convert to `Base64` using `JavaScript` and `C#`, it gives me two different values. what is the reason for this?

**JavaScript Code**

```
  function LoadSvg() {
            var main = document.getElementById('svgimg');
            var data = main.innerHTML;
            debugger;
            var base64blob = Base64.encode(data);
            alert(base64blob);
            var image2 = document.getElementById('Img2');
            image2.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + base64blob;
        }
```

**C# code**

```
string val=litSvg.Text;
byte[] arr = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(val);
string toBaseVal = Convert.ToBase64String(arr);      
ExternalHtml = 
   "<img id=\"dfs\" src=\"data:image/svg+xml;base64," + toBaseVal + "\" />";
```

in JavaScript `main` value and c# `val` values are same. how this happens? if I need to same same value in java script out put, how can I do that?

**Edit :**

val value :

```
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' width='470px' height='310px'><line x1='40' y1='10' x2='40' y2='250'style='stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width: 1' />...
```

main value :

```
 <svg id="svg-code" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="470px" height="310px"> <line x1="40" y1="10" x2="40" y2="250" style="stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width: 1"></line>
```

**O/P values :**

base64blob : CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8.....

toBaseVal  : PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0naHR0cDov ....

Comment: What are the values? Try it with a very short, basic example.

Comment: you might try decoding the base64 value back to see what the difference is - sometimes Base64 algorithms pad the end with 0's

Comment: main & val contain html value. (same div). problem occurs when i assign that value to img tag, then java script generated image correctly. but when i do same thing with c#, then image is not generate.

Comment: you are UTF8 encoding the value in c#

Comment: @Jimmy - even i use ` System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(val);` it gives different values

Comment: have you tried Ascii.GetBytes(val)?

Comment: can you post the first 12 characters of main and val as well as the first 16 chars of the resulting Base64 encoded versions - I can probably tell you exactly what is going wrong from that

Comment: To start off with they are different values (i.e. main != val) - but I suspect there is still an issue with the encoding (the first 4 chars of the Base64 should be the same)

Comment: looks like your javascript base64 may be padded at the beginning with white space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Javascript decoded buffer contains whitespace at the beginning

```
LINEFEED SPACE SPACE SPACE < ...


$ echo "CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8" | base64 -d | hexdump -C -n 32
00000000  0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |.               |
00000010  20 3c                                             | <|
```

Your C# decoded buffer is correct

```
$ echo "PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0naHR0cDov" | base64 -d | hexdump -C -n 16
00000000  3c 73 76 67 20 78 6d 6c  6e 73 3d 27 68 74 74 70  |<svg xmlns='http|
00000010
```

It is possible that they will both give the desired result though

Comment: in here this base64 should generate image. problem occurs in c# and it is not generated image

Comment: the quoting differs between the two (single quotes and double quotes) and the line tag has a closing tag in C# - this might be the next thing you check

Answer (score 1):

**The problem is spaces here.**

Remove leading and trailing spaces from your svg file. In addition - remove all excesive whitespace too ie. collapse 1+ whitespace to one whitespace and in your C# - read+convert your file like this:

```
byte[] arr = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(svf_file);
string toBaseVal = Convert.ToBase64String(arr);
```

Leave encodings alone.

One code calculates base64 with excesive spaces and the other without (as it removes them implicitly) - read [innerHTML](http://help.dottoro.com/ljdkwhqf.php)

Comment: this is not a file. its just text